# Python FuncAnimation is saved only 30%

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, ffmpeg

I am trying to make a movie out of data I've calculated. I am using ffmpeg writer. When I start the animation in Spyder it is working fine and goes to the end, but when I try to save it it goes only for first 30% of animation. How can I make it to save the whole animation?

Here is a bit of code( it's long); MM is place where the matrices are stored (1200 of them).

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
nx = 10
ny = 10
X=np.linspace(0, Lx, nx)
Y=np.linspace(0, Ly, ny)   
Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = Writer(fps=15, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1)

plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
im = plt.contourf(X, Y, MM[0], np.linspace(T_ok,np.max(MM[-1]),150), cmap =     cm.hot)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')  
plt.colorbar(im)

def anime(i):
    ax.cla()
    im = ax.contourf(X, Y, MM[i], np.linspace(T_ok,np.max(MM[-1]),150), cmap = cm.hot)
    plt.title('%5.3f'%i)
    return im,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, anime)
anim.save('anime.mp4', writer=writer)
```

EDIT: I just set frames to 10000 and it's working, but I would like to know why. There are 1200 matrices that should be plotted.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "I set frames to 1000"? Where did you do that? I'm experiencing this problem.

Answer (score 2):

This question is pretty old, but just in case someone stumbles upon it while looking for the answer (like I did), [this comment](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/animation.py#L1490) made me understand that for custom frame generators, you need to manually set the `save_count` member of `FuncAnimation` to make the video save the whole animation.

I.e., if you want to go through an array `times` with your `anim` instance of `FuncAnimation`, you need:

```
# either at instantiation
# anim = FuncAnimation(..., save_count=len(times))
# or after some time, if you need to customize it later
anim.save_count = len(times)
anim.save('anime.mp4', writer=writer)
```